# Multiple Order By Statements in Query Builder?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony 3 project.  And I am sending an array of varying length to a query builder.  The query builder looks like this:

```
function findByQuery($sortBy) {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
                    ->leftJoin('d.cat', 'dc')
                    ->leftJoin('d.dog', 'dd')
                    ->leftJoin('d.rabbit', 'rr')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->execute();

}
```

I want to use the $sortBy parameter to order the results.  However the issue is that sometimes the $sortBy (which is an array) will sometimes only contain one element with a key and an order by setting (e.g. ASC or DESC), and other times will contain several keys.  In either case I want to be able to sort the results by all the elements.  Is there a simple way of doing this?

Many thanks,

Comment: You can assign the `QueryBuilder` instance to a variable up to the point before calling `getQuery()` and then with simple `foreach()` you can call the `addOrderBy()` method as many times as you want and lastly return something like `$builder->getQuery()->execute()`.

Comment: Sorry I don't full understand how I can do this with the addOrderBy method?

Answer (score 1):

This is as simple as:

```
$sortBy = [
    'd.property1'  => 'ASC',
    'd.property2'  => 'DESC'
];

function findByQuery(array $sortBy) {
    // create QueryBuilder
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->leftJoin('d.cat', 'dc')
        ->leftJoin('d.dog', 'dd')
        ->leftJoin('d.rabbit', 'rr');

    foreach ($sortBy as $property => $dir) {
        $qb->addOrderBy($property, $dir);
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

Comment: probably the array keys need to be with the table alias like `d.property1`